# How to remove zeros after the decimal point

Tags: genexus

I want to remove the zeros after the decimal point and display

Input 123.111  → Display 123.111

Input 123.000  → Display 123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a string replace.

Here is the documentation:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?12710,Replace+method

An example would be:

&String1 = '123.000'
&String2 = &String1.Replace('.000', '')

If you are starting with a numeric variable, for example, N(10,3), then convert it to a string first:
&String1 = &Numeric1.ToString().Trim()

Answer (score 2):

As Sergio said, the easiest way is using a replace method.
You can also verify your variable/attribute before using the replace.

```
if &your_variable.ToString().EndsWith(".000")
   &your_variable.ToString().replace(".000", "")
endif
```

Remember that if *&your_variable* is Numeric you will have to convert it to string, since the replace method takes a Char, LongVarChar or VarChar data type as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to assign the variable with decimals into a variable without decimals

Example:

&aux2 = 3.2   // &aux2 is defined as Numeric 4.2

&aux3 = &aux2   // &aux3 is defined as Numeric 4

Result: &aux3 =  3

A second option is to use the [round function](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8486,Round%20function)

Example:

&aux2 = 3.2   // &aux2 is defined as Numeric 4.2

&aux2.round(0)

Result: &aux2 = 3.00